# Python attribute error on TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I am just starting to learn python and follow guide on internet and i am already dont know how to solve problem just because i following the guide.

so, i learn about OOP in atribute. this is my class where if i add new person, i will return attribute of number_of_people equal the person i added based on this code

```
class Person:
    number_of_people = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Person.add_person()

    @classmethod
    def number_of_people(cls):
        return cls.number_of_people

    @classmethod
    def add_person(cls):
        cls.number_of_people += 1
```

i try to add 2 person

```
p1 = Person("Tim")
p2 = Person("Jill")
```

but when i print

```
print(Person.number_of_people())
```

it return `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'`
i already try to cast it to type of string `print(str(Person.number_of_people()))` and still error and i dont know what to do in `add_person(cls)` am i missing something in the method? i am just confuse because tutorial works fine. I am using Python 3.9.0

Comment: You've got a function with the same name as a variable

Comment: Change: `def number_of_people(cls):` to something like: `def get_number_of_people(cls):`

Comment: or just get rid of the method..

Comment: @Sayse wow, that helps me. Thanks, but why on tutorial works totally fine? or it is just apply on newer version?

Comment: @quamrana thanks for your help, i just wonder why tutorial works fine, is it only on newer version?

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you're referring to but they won't be giving a variable the same name as their method

Comment: @Sayse i will give you link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeznW_7DlB0 48:32

Comment: @AgusHandoko it doesn't work fine. If your tutorial is saying the above works fine then it is wrong. Perhaps there is a difference you aren't noticing

Comment: @AgusHandoko - Their function has a trailing underscore. (Which is a terrible design decision btw)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, maybe it is not applied on newer version, thanks for the response

Comment: @AgusHandoko no **it has nothing to do with python versions**. This is *always* the behavior in Python. As pointed out by Sayse, the method is actually named with an `_` at the end.

Comment: @Sayse i thought every python developer does that, thanks for your tip

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ohh i see, so i can avoid that. i missed that underscore in my code

Comment: @Sayse hey, how can i set your comment as an answer?

Comment: @AgusHandoko - You can't but at the same time you don't need to... [so] is about creating a resource of questions and answers that will help the wider audience and a typo/misunderstanding isn't really likely to help future readers